# Apache .htaccess whitelist doesn't block Tomcat with Mod_jk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, mod-jk

My problem is, that I recently set up a Tomcat7 application container with Apache2.2 Frontend. As the project is still under development I am controlling access by an IP whitelist set up in .htaccess for the domain.

I set up mod_jk via AJP13 to Tomcat, it works absolutely fine, except the fact that .htaccess doesn't block the forward for Tomcat. In other words if you enter www.mydomain.com from a "black" IP, you get forwarded to the error page but if you enter www.mydomain.com/AppContext you slip through Apache into Tomcat

I started messing with urlrewritefilter with Tomcat, but for some reason it didn't work.
I am wondering if there is any way to set up .htaccess or apache instead to block requests forwarded to Tomcat similarly to request for Apache?

Also noticed a dramatic speed decrease when using it like that, us that common when using Apache as a frontend?

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess files will work only when Apache is using a <Directory> based configuration (in httpd.conf). In case of mod_jk, matching requests (as specified by JkMount directive) will simply be forwarded to the AJP connector.

Use `<Location>` to control access instead:

```xml
<Location "/AppContext">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from .myCompany.local
</Location>
```

See [`<Location> Directive>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) for details.

Comment: Excellent solution, thanks! 

What's your view about the second part of my problem? I mean it is expected that there is some sort of delay because of the port forward, but I thought it wouldn't be noticeable. (I have a 2 Core 2GB RAM VPS)

Comment: You're welcome! Under normal circumstances, no slowdown should be noticeable - Apache + Tomcat is standard production environment. Be sure to delete any remains of your URL rewriting experiments and check again. One more point: change `JkLogLevel` (in mod_jk.conf) from `info` to `error`. Its default setting generates loads of log lines which can slow down operation.

Comment: Awesome solution! I was looking at doing something on the Tomcat site in Java in our app but this fixes the issue without wasting any resources in the request processing path beyond the front facing Apache webserver - much nicer, easier and no CPU used on the Tomcat side.!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found a solution which may solve your case too.
Use a reverse proxy server like [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) or [Squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html) to redirect the traffic Apache Tomcat. Both of them can use **htpassword** for authentication and hence, will serve your need. If you want to use Apache as frontend then backend can be nginx which in turn will redirect to Tomcat after proper authentication. It may have a performance hit, though.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10